# Authentication between Android app and Google Apps Script web app

Tags: android, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an Android app that call a Google Apps Script published as a web app. The script uses advanced Google services (e.g. I enabled the Fusion Tables API).

Now I don't know what to select in developer console when I add:

```
credentials -> New Credentials -> OAuth Client ID
```

If I select Android the authorization flow (OAuth and access/refresh token) works well, but when I post to the script the answer is:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that appID in live and also verified that account has been verified mobile.

Comment: I didn't understand your suggestion